# Gatsby Graphql Reading image

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I want to read a path to an image file from YAML, and use the `gatsby-image` to create responsive images, but it doesn't let me do what I want.

data.yaml

```
fileKey: data
profile:
  - name: Foo
    image: image.jpg
  - name: Bar
    image: image2.jpg
```

My query looks like:

```
query DataQuery {
  pagesYaml(fileKey: {eq: "data"}) {
    profile {
      name
      image {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 2048, quality: 100) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me this error `Field "image" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields`.

However, this below works.

```
query DataQuery {
  pagesYaml(fileKey: {eq: "data"}) {
    profile {
      name
    }
    profileImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "image.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
    profileImage2: file(relativePath: { eq: "image2.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The nice thing about the first query is that I can place the profile image inside the `profile`, so it's easier to manage the data in JavaScript. Is it possible to place the image inside the `profile` object in the query?

Here's my `gatsby-config.js`. The images are stored in `src/img/`.

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const yaml = require('./src/yaml');

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Gatsby + Netlify CMS Starter',
    description:
      'This repo contains an example business website that is built with Gatsby, and Netlify CMS.It follows the JAMstack architecture by using Git as a single source of truth, and Netlify for continuous deployment, and CDN distribution.',
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-robots-txt',
      options: {
        policy: [{ userAgent: '*', disallow: '/' }]
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
      options: {
        exclude: [`/admin`]
      }
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    'gatsby-transformer-yaml',
    {
      // keep as first gatsby-source-filesystem plugin for gatsby image support
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/static/img`,
        name: 'uploads',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
        name: 'pages',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/img`,
        name: 'images',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/data`,
        name: 'data',
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
      options: {
        engines: { yaml },
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-relative-images',
            options: {
              name: 'uploads',
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
            options: {
              // It's important to specify the maxWidth (in pixels) of
              // the content container as this plugin uses this as the
              // base for generating different widths of each image.
              maxWidth: 2048,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files',
            options: {
              destinationDir: 'static',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader',
      options: {
        custom: {
          families: ['Appli Mincho']
        }
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms',
      options: {
        modulePath: `${__dirname}/src/cms/cms.js`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-purgecss', // purges all unused/unreferenced css rules
      options: {
        develop: true, // Activates purging in npm run develop
        purgeOnly: ['/all.sass'], // applies purging only on the bulma css file
      },
    }, // must be after other CSS plugins
    'gatsby-plugin-netlify', // make sure to keep it last in the array
  ],
  // for avoiding CORS while developing Netlify Functions locally
  // read more: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/api-proxy/#advanced-proxying
  developMiddleware: app => {
    app.use(
      '/.netlify/functions/',
      proxy({
        target: 'http://localhost:9000',
        pathRewrite: {
          '/.netlify/functions/': '',
        },
      })
    )
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely occurring because Gatsby is inferring your `profile.image` field as a String instead of a File. This can happen if one or more of the provided path strings does not resolve to a file when you boot Gatsby. Note that Gatsby will not rerun type-inference for existing fields after it boots, so you will need to restart the development server to pick up these changes.

Comment: I double-checked it again, but it still doesn't work. I pasted by `gatsby-config.js`.

Comment: If your `data.yml` is in `src/data` and your images are in `src/img` then your `profile.image` fields should look something like `../img/image.jpg`, not `image.jpg`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but having to specify the path relative to the location of the yml should be unnecessary. I set up the `gatsby-source-filesystem` plugin to specify the image folder, so I shouldn't need to do so. What's missing here?

Comment: Also, if I query image using `gatsby-transformer-rewark`,  I don't need to query for images in the `static` folder relative to the Markdown file location. So, it's weird that I need to a path relative to the file location in this case..

Comment: I think I figured it out. I think it works for `gatsby-transformer-remark` because of this plugin `gatsby-remark-relative-images`. Thanks.